# How to append a row in indexed data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting a `NaN` values when I append a row in indexed dataframe. Can someone help me in fixing the issue?

Here is my code:

```
mycolumns = ['A', 'B']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=mycolumns)
rows = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
for row in rows:
   df.loc[len(df)] = row
print(df) 
df = df.set_index('A')
print("\n index\n",df)
print("\n=================")

dict = { 'A': 2 ,'B':5}
df = df.append(dict,ignore_index=True)
print("\n======================\n")
print(df)
```

Here is the output:

```
   A  B
   0  1  2
   1  3  4
   2  5  6

  index
     B
A   
1   2
3   4
5   6

=================

======================

B    A
0  2  NaN
1  4  NaN
2  6  NaN
3  5  2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot append a dictionary to a dataframe, as df.append() requires another dataframe as the parameter. You would need to go around a little bit to make this work:

```
mycolumns = ['A', 'B']
dict = { 'A': 2 ,'B':5}
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[dict.get('A'), dict.get('B')]], columns=mycolumns)
df.append(df2)
```

Here we first create a new dataframe from the dictionary (i would also suggest changing the dictionary structure to `{'val_key': [2, 5],}` if you can do that).

Then we can use `df.append(df2)` to append the newly created dataframe to the old one.